# Calculating the elements of Jacobian Matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

A Jacobian Matrix is defined as :

[image]

If we have discrete data and we are applying any numerical modelling approach how will end elements of the matrix be calculated.
for example : if central difference is applied then df(i)=df(i+1)-df(i-1) .based on this df(1) cannot be calculated.

Comment: the subsripts refer to the different dimensions of the problem space; your question as asked seems to be interpreting them as n values of a single variable. For the Jacobian to make sense there must be an n-dimensional space, and the n functions are the transformations of one set of n descriptive variables to a new set. Each variable should have available multiple values near the multidimensional point for which the Jacobian is to be evaluated.

Comment: my doubt is that suppose we use central difference scheme then it is possible to compute elements in first row or last row since there are no elements before(or after)